# How to store feature (sparse matrix) and label (array matrix) into TFRecordDataset - Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, tfidfvectorizer

Applied TF-IDF and converted each document into 1*2000 (features), so i have total document of 10824 and the sparse matrix is 10824 * 2000 and the associated label's shape is 10824 * 35 (0 or 1 each of 35 labels)

Can anyone help me, how to store those into TFRecordDataset (Feature & label)?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Your can use `tensorflow.Example` [proto](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/core/example/example.proto) to store features and labels. For a concrete example, a document should look like below:

```
features: {
  feature: {
    key  : "features"
    value: {
      bytes_list: {
        value: ["this", "is", "an", "example", "of", "your", "features"]
      }
    }
  }
  feature: {
    key  : "labels"
    value: {
      bytes_list: {
        # Assume "news" and "sports" are two of your 35 labels.
        value: ["news", "sports"]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

(If you already convert strings to integers (IDs), you can use `int64_list` instead of `bytes_list` and you won't need to use a vocabulary file later on.)

Now your whole dataset is a `TFRecordDataset` of `tensorflow.Example` protos. You can use [`tf.dataset` API](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset) to read and parse like below:

```
d = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(FLAGS.input_file)
d = d.map(parser_fn)
```

You just need to write a `parser_fn` using [`tf.parse_example`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r1.0/api_docs/python/tf/parse_example). Your `feature_spec` will look like this:

```
feature_spec = {
  "token":  tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
  "labels": tf.VarLenFeature(tf.string),
}
```

Due to the sparse nature of your features and labels, you will probably need to use Categorical vocabulary columns or embedding columns to represent them in an [`Estimator`](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/premade_estimators). For more details, see https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/feature_columns.